# How can I open multiple servers in phpmyadmin without log out?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I upgraded phpmyadmin to 4.8.3. Before I could have multiple tabs in google with different servers (so I can compare/copy dev data and prod data) and now if I open another tab and switch server I will be logged out...

How can I config it please?

Answer (score 1):

In short, as of today you can't. It was possible in [version 4.7.1](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12301), but it was "broken" again [in 4.8](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/6262#issuecomment-427314834). There's an [open issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14235) to fix it.